# Number of binary trees with given height

Tags: data-structures, counting

I was wondering how many binary trees we have with height of $h$ with $n$ nodes(another question is how many binary trees we have with height $ \lfloor{lg (n)}\rfloor$).

Edit: I forgot to add the number of nodes.

Comment: What did you try? Where did you get stuck? What is $n$?

Comment: How do you define height? (there are two common definitions differing by $1$)

Comment: I forgot to to say number of nodes, it is $n$.

Comment: problem setter was not very precise, I think for definition of height we consider height of root to be zero

Comment: this might help you: http://stackoverflow.com/a/13093274/550393

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take the height $h$ as the length of the longest root to leaf path. After fixing the root, we count the number in two cases:

1. both left and right subtrees are of height $h$. number of trees  $=A_h^2$
2. only one subtree has height $h$. number of trees $=2 \cdot A_h \cdot (A_0+A_1+...+A_{h-1})$

$$
A_{h+1} = A_h^2 + 2 \cdot A_h \cdot (A_0+A_1+...+A_{h-1})
$$

Comment: I think this is the right answer, but can we get a closed form ?

Comment: This is not the exact anwer to the question, since it does not restrict the number of nodes to $n$. By the way, for a closed form look at [A001699](http://oeis.org/A001699)

Answer (score 5):

I assume that a binary tree is given by the following specification: a binary tree is either (a) empty or (b) is composed of a root and two (ordered) subtrees.

I also assume that height is defined so that a complete binary tree of height $h$ has $2^{h+1}-1$ nodes (for example, a single node has height $0$).

Let $A_h$ be the number of binary trees with height at most $h$. Then $A_{-1} = 1$ and $A_h = 1 + A_{h-1}^2$. This is [A003095](http://oeis.org/A003095). The number of trees with height exactly $h$ is $A_h - A_{h-1}$, which is [A001699](http://oeis.org/A001699). Both sequences have asymptotics of the form $\alpha^{2^h}$ for some $\alpha > 1$.

Comment: what is $A^{i} _{j}$ and what does $i$ stands for?

Comment: as I said, It was a test question, and the correct answer was $ 2^h \choose n - 2^h +1 $ can you explain this ?

Comment: The author of the question must have had a different definition of binary trees in mind. The link agrees with me that $A_h - A_{h-1}$ is the number of binary trees of height $h$.

Answer (score 1):

Let us assume that the number of nodes are $n$. Also, consider that $a_{n,h}$ represents the number of different binary trees with $n$ nodes having height $h$.
We construct the solution recursively.

Consider that $m$ is the current root, then for a binary tree of height $h$ we consider two cases:

1. The left subtree has the height of $h-1$. Also, we know that the left subtree contains $m-1$ nodes. So, the number of binary trees with  $m-1$ nodes and height are given by $a_{m-1,h-1}$. Now, the right subtree can have any height in $[0, h-1]$, so the number of ways of forming right subtree is given by $\sum\limits_{i=1}^{h-1}a_{n-m,i} $. Therefore, total ways in this case are:  $ a_{m-1,h-1}\sum\limits_{i=1}^{h-1}a_{n-m,i} $
2. Now, consider that left subtree has a height less than $h-1$. Then, the right subtree(consists of $n-m$ nodes) must have a height equal to $h-1$ which is given by $a_{n-m, h-1}$. Now, the left subtree can have any height in $[0, h-2]$, so the number of ways of forming left subtree is given by $\sum\limits_{i=1}^{h-2}a_{m-1,i} $. Therefore, total ways in this case are:  $ a_{n-m,h-1}\sum\limits_{i=1}^{h-2}a_{m-1,i} $

As we have $n$ different ways to choose the node, we have the number of different binary trees of height $h$ and $n$ nodes given by the following formula:

$a_{n,h}$ = $\sum\limits_{m=1}^{n} (a_{m-1,h-1}\sum\limits_{i=1}^{h-1}a_{n-m,i}+a_{n-m,h-1}\sum\limits_{i=1}^{h-2}a_{m-1,i})$

This recurrence relation can be solved using the base case as:

1. $a_{0,0}=1$
2. $a_{i,0}=a_{0,i}=0$,  for all $i>0$